# Numpy array dimentions mismatch when reshaping Tensor with three channels

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am building a siamese network on the `Omniglot` Keras dataset, an image dataset. The issue comes in when I try to reshape the dataset, saying the following:

```
cannot reshape array of size 212562000 into shape (19280,105,105,3)
```

However, when I check the shape of the Dataset it is

```
train_images.shape
(19280, 105, 105)
```

I am confused about where the `212562000` is gotten from. Below is the code used up to where it fails.

```
 ' Load Omniglot dataset ' 
# load the training data
(ds_train, ds_test), ds_info = tfds.load(name='Omniglot', split=['train', 'test'], with_info=True)


# Convert labels to numpy arrays for manipulation
train_labels = np.array([[glyph["alphabet"].numpy() for glyph in ds_train]])    


# Convert images to numpy arrays for manipulation
train_images = np.array([glyph["image"].numpy()[:, :, 0] for glyph in ds_train])    


# Re-shape images for input layer
train_images = train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0], train_images.shape[1], train_images.shape[2], 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Tensor one shape `(19280, 105, 105)` usually means that you have 19280 samples that are grayscale images of size 105 by 105 (it can be seen as a shape of `(19280, 105, 105, 1)`) while Tensors of RGB images have a shape `(19280, 105, 105, 3)`.

The problem is that you are trying to reshape a Tensor of grayscale (or one-channel) images to a tensor of color images. You cannot do that because shapes are not compatible, hence the error. A tensor of shape `(19280, 105, 105)` has `19280 x 105 x 105 = 212562000` elements and you cannot reshape it into a tensor of size `(19280, 105, 105, 3)` having `19280 x 105 x 105 x 3 = 637686000` elements.

The problem is probably in the third step where you extract Numpy arrays from the dataset:

```py
train_images = np.array([glyph["image"].numpy()[:, :, 0] for glyph in ds_train])
```

The images are probably colored one and you are taking the index 0 in the third dimension so you only take the first color dimension (the red one). Try to remove `[:, :, 0]` to get the 3 color channels.

If the images are grayscale ones, replace `3` in your reshape operation by `1` since grayscale images only have 1 channel.